# Order by inside Case in Order By

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, case, firebird

I have this database

```
    ID  Title
    1   Unassaign
    6   Prima
    7   Adi
```

I want to make `ID` 1 to be display last but the other are sort by their title

Desired results:

```
    ID  Title
    7   Adi
    6   Prima
    1   Unassaign
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT a.ID_WB, a.TITLE, a.DESCRIPTION, a.AUTHOR, a.DATECREATE, a.DATEUPDATE
FROM WORKBOOK a
order by case when ID_WB = 1 then 1
else 0 end
```

I tried insert `Order By` after `else` but it always return SQL error..
Is there a workaroud to this problem?
Thanks

PS: The first `Order by`should sort by ID

Comment: Move the case to the select list, and order by that column?

Answer (score 3):

Use two expressions in the `order by`:

```
order by (case when ID_WB = 1 then 1 else 0 end), title
```